# IndexedDB - Adding a store to an existing database?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am attempting to create a simple key/value store (akin to `localStorage`) that is powered by IndexedDB.

```js
class LocalStorageAsync {
  constructor(storeName?: string)
  getItem(key: string): Promise<string>
  setItem(key: string, value: string): Promise<void>
}
```

When instantiated, the constructor creates the database with a default store name if unspecified.

```js
class LocalStorageAsync {
  //...

  constructor(storeName = 'default') {
    const openRequest = indexedDB.open('LocalStorageAsync')

    openRequest.onupgradeneeded = () => {
      const db = oRequest.result
      db.createObjectStore(storeKey)
    }

    this.#database = new Promise(resolve =>
      openRequest.onsuccess = () => resolve(oRequest.result)
  }

  //...
}
```

I want to be able to partition the database using store names so it has to create a store if it doesn't exist in the database.

```js
new LocalStorageAsync() // will create `LocalStorageAsync.default`
new LocalStorageAsync('foo') // will create `LocalStorageAsync.foo`
```

Initially, I attempted to do this within the `onsuccess` callback.

```js
class LocalStorageAsync {
  //...

  constructor(storeName = 'default') {
    const openRequest = indexedDB.open('LocalStorageAsync')

    this.#database = new Promise(resolve => {
      openRequest.onsuccess = () => {
        if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains(storeKey)) {
          // This cannot be called in "onsuccess"
          db.createObjectStore(storeKey)
        }

        resolve(oRequest.result)
      }
    }
  }

  //...
}
```

I came to realise that `db.createObjectStore()` can only be called from within the `onupgradeneeded` callback which is only triggered when there is a version bump to the database or when the database is newly created.

The database versions are not important to me but I still need to trigger the `onupgradeneeded` callback to add a store.

Is it possible to trigger the `onupgradeneeded` from the `onsuccess` callback? Perhaps by naively incrementing a database version bump?

```js
openRequest.onsuccess = () => {
  if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains(storeKey)) {
    // not a real method
    db.bumpVersion(db.version + 1)
  }
}
```

Am I better off just creating a new database entirely with a concatenated name (`LocalStorageAsync.${storeName}`)?

Answer (score 0):

If your condition is whether to create a store, consider storing a version property within your objects instead.

Generally avoid designing a system where the schema has to change to support changes to data at runtime. Schema's should be relatively static.